# Problem accessing SQL Server from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to implement a backup management script i found at http://sev17.com/2011/03/restore-and-relocate-database-files-using-powershell/

The article says it depends on SQLPSX version 2.3.2.1 or higher - I have the most current version.

attempting to execute this line:

```
$server = get-sqlserver $sqlserver
```

results in:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlserver\SQLServer.psm1:68 char:24
+     { $con = new-object <<<<  ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection") $sqlserver }
```

result of get-module -listAvailable

```
    ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands                                                           
    ---------- ----                      ----------------                                                           
    Script     adoLib                    {}                                                                         
    Manifest   Agent                     {Get-AgentTargetServerGroup, Get-AgentProxyAccount, Get-AgentJobSchedule...
    Script     ISECreamBasic             {}                                                                         
    Script     mySQLLib                  {}                                                                         
    Script     OracleClient              {}                                                                         
    Script     OracleIse                 {}                                                                         
    Script     PBM                       {}                                                                         
    Script     PerfCounters              {}                                                                         
    Manifest   Pscx                      {}                                                                         
    Manifest   Repl                      {Get-ReplEnumSubscriptions2, Get-ReplPublisherMonitor, Get-ReplEnumPubli...
    Manifest   ShowMbrs                  {Get-ShowMbrs, Set-ShowMbrs, New-ShowMbrs, Get-GroupUser}                  
    Script     SQLIse                    {}                                                                         
    Manifest   SQLMaint                  {Get-SqlIndexFragmentation, New-UserMember, Invoke-SqlIndexRebuild, Get-...
    Manifest   SQLParser                 {Test-SqlScript, Out-SqlScript}                                            
    Script     SQLProfiler               {}                                                                         
    Script     SQLPSX                    {}                                                                         
    Manifest   sqlserver                 {Get-SqlScripter, Get-SqlIndexFragmentation, Remove-SqlServerRoleMember,...
    Manifest   SSIS                      {New-ISItem, Get-ISPackage, Get-ISItem, Copy-ISItemFileToSQL...}           
    Manifest   WPK                       {}                                                                         
    Manifest   AppLocker                 {}                                                                         
    Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}                                                                         
    Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}                                                                         
    Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}                                                                         
    Manifest   WebAdministration         {}
```

RE: SMO

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended")
```

results:

```
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll                             
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll                                                   
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll                                   
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Comment: Could you post the result of this: `get-module -listAvailable`

Comment: You need to SMO installed as indicated in the readme file and documentation http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the Assembly containing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection type (which I think is Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) is loaded first:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
```

Comment: Does it produce any output? You should see some info about the assembly. If it doesn't produce any output then you don't have that assembly in your GAC, meaning it won't be able to load it and therefore won't be able to load the ServerConnection type, giving you the error above.

Comment: True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo\10.0.0.0__89845...

Answer (score 3):

For me works with

```bsh
Import-Module -Name SqlServer
```

It could stay in script
NOTE:

- Windows Server 2016
- Before I have installed

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

- With [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName works only on windows 10 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is just about the worst answer ever but...
Seems like there *might* be something wrong with your SMO or something.  You could try loading [SP3 for SQL 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27594) or just try re-installing SSMS 2008.  Installing the 2008 R2 version of SSMS could be an option as well.

Again, not the greatest answer in the world but might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

The powershell components are only installed if you have powershell 2.0 installed at the time of SSMS setup. Powershell is normally already setup on the machine unless you are using Windows Server 2008.  Ensure that powershell 2.0 is installed before installing SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

$sc = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection

Error:
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded

For this issue ,

Please Ensure micro soft sqlserver management object 2012(x64)is installed.
and go ahead check the dll files if present in given path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies"